# Xamarin Android building custom dynamic buttons from a database with Custom Skins and Click Events

Tags: android, button, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building a Xamarin Android App and I have a section that I need to build custom dynamic buttons.  The method below will build these buttons dynamically but I need to call a xml file in my @drawable folder for the background and styling of the button and I am not sure how to acheive this.  I also need to create the click event for each of these buttons but I'm not sure how to do this.  Below is my code for the dynamic buttons.

```
    protected async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Vm.ShowCurrentUser();
        buttonCollection = await Vm.ShowButtons();
        foreach (UserButtonLabel label in buttonCollection)
        {
            Button custButton = new Button(this);
            custButton.Id = label.iAvailableTimeStatusID;


            custButton.Text = label.nStatus;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            ButtonLayout.AddView(custButton, lp);

        }
    }
```

Now I need the click delegate but I also need to figure out how to call the drawable style of the button.  Below is how I would have built the button in xml.

```
            <Button
                        android:id="@+id/childButton"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/GreenButton"
                        android:text="Place Holder text"
                        style="@style/button_text"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

Maybe there is a way to call the button from a different xml?

Answer (score 1):

So I basically found the easiest way from a logic and UI point of view was to create a listview that has only buttons.  That way the UI will build buttons with a vertical scroll.  I used a xml template, a adapter, and the logic for the adapter.  The great part of this is there a click event in the adapter for each of the buttons.

AXML CustomButton.axml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/childButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/GreenButton"
        android:text="Clock In"
        style="@style/button_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter with a custom object named UserButtonLabel
CustomButtonAdapter :

```
    public class CustomButtonAdapter : BaseAdapter<UserButtonLabel>
    {
        Activity context;
        ObservableCollection<UserButtonLabel> list;
        public CustomButtonAdapter(Activity _context, ObservableCollection<UserButtonLabel> _list) : base()
        {
            this.context = _context;
            this.list = _list;
        }

        public override UserButtonLabel this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return list[index];
            }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return list.Count;
            }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Android.Views.View view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomButton, null);
            }

            UserButtonLabel label = this[position];

            Button button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.childButton);
            button1.Tag = label.nStatus;
            button1.Text = label.nStatus;
            button1.SetOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(this.context));

            return view;
        }

        private class ButtonClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
        {
            private Activity activity;

            public ButtonClickListener(Activity activity)
            {
                this.activity = activity;
            }

            public async void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
            {
                string name = (string)v.Tag;
                string text = string.Format("{0} Button Click.", name);
                Toast.MakeText(this.activity, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                await Vm.ClockCommand();
            }
        }

        private static UserViewModel Vm
        {
            get
            {
                return App.Locator.UserTimeTracker;
            }
        }
    }
```

Custom Button Label Object

```
    public class UserButtonLabel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _iAvailableTimeStatusID;
        public int iAvailableTimeStatusID
        {
            get
            {
                return _iAvailableTimeStatusID;
            }
            set
            {
                _iAvailableTimeStatusID = value;
            }
        }

        private string _nStatus;
        public string nStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _nStatus;
            }

            set
            {
                _nStatus = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Activity Code for calling and instantiating

```
    protected async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        buttonCollection = await Vm.ShowButtons();
        if (buttonCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            listAdapter = new CustomButtonAdapter(this, buttonCollection);
            ButtonListview.Adapter = listAdapter;
        }

    }
```

There wasn't a need for a onitemclicklistener on the listview as the buttons each have a click event.